# Node JS 3-Way form submission

Tags: javascript, node.js, variables, express, module

im writing a NodeApp and i was wondering if it would be possible that if i have App.js file, that defines an index, with form, then when i submit the form, i would have a file that validates etc the form and sends the data to the third file. Would that be possible?

*App.js*

```
- redirects to index, where the form is
```

*ValidateForm.js*

```
- validation of the form and getting the data
```

*RandomFile.js*

```
- get data from the validation
```

Comment: If you are using Express then why send it to different files. Why not make each file a piece of middleware and just go from one middleware to the next. http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Comment: Could you show me an example ?